# Chef - Call action from other action in LWRP

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, lwrp

I am defining a provider as below:

```
action :start do
 ...
end

action :stop do 
 ...
end

action :restart do
 ...
end
```

Now instead of rewriting the implementation of `stop` and `start` in `restart`, I would like to call `action :stop` and then `action :start` in `action :restart`, like this:

```
action :restart do
  action :stop
  action :start
end
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

**EDIT** - As mentioned in Coderanger answer, the solution is:

```
action :restart do 
  action_stop
  action_start
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `action_start` and `action_stop`.

Comment: I wonder what's wrong, but when I put ```action_stop``` and ```action_start``` in ```action :restart```, ```action :stop``` and ```action :start``` are executed twice. When I just paste the code for start / stop, everything is fine.

Comment: See the following pastebin for comparison purposes: the first calls each action two times, the second works fine.
http://pastebin.com/6r94LMNA
http://pastebin.com/3WHwQhNF

Comment: I don't know what is in `init` but it would indeed get called twice.

Comment: Also you are using a bunch of class variables, I really don't think you mean to be doing that.

Comment: This is the content of ```libraries.rb ```defining the ```init``` function: http://pastebin.com/qULUAsgk

Comment: I don't know what you wrote, but it is *not* a Chef resource. Please follow the standard style if you want your code to work.

Comment: To be clear, this answer is correct, however what you wrote is not a Chef resource/provider and thus does not follow the same rules.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct answer. I have just tried this and it seems that this calls action_stop and action_start in compile time. I was trying to run something like this:

```
action :create do
  # steps to create resource
  directory '/test' do
    ...
  end

  action_config
end

action :config do   
  ... # configuration   
  template '/test/config' do   
    ...   
  end 
end
```

It has failed because :config ran first (before directory has been created).

I have tried to put action_config into ruby_block -- which seems to work, but I'm not sure if arguments are passed correctly.